# Read multiple partitioned S3 folders into PySpark dataframes

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark

I have and S3 bucket saved in date partitions as following:

```
s3://mydata/date=2023-05-01
s3://mydata/date=2023-05-02
...
s3://mydata/date=2023-08-15
```

I want to read all partitions of a certain months, say June into one PySpark dataframe. This is how I would read just one partition (i.e.e one day):

```
df = spark.read.text("s3://mydata/date=2023-06-01")
```

How would I modify that to read for the entire month of June without having multiple dataframes and merging them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read files using the wildcard, which is

```
df = spark.read.text("s3://mydata/date=2023-06-*")
```

If you need to `date` as a column, you need to use `basePath`:

```
df = spark.read.option("basePath", "s3://mydata/").text("s3://mydata/date=2023-06-*")
```